# Vba Excel Trust access to the VBA project model

Tags: excel, vba, trust

I need to execute the following lines of code for my client, the problem is that in order to access them I must have activated a certain option within the project, is there any way to avoid that?

[image]

```
Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\System32\mshtml.tlb"
Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\System32\msxml6.dll"
```

They are a couple of libraries necessary for the execution of my Macro.

The macro that I am running is as follows:

```
Sub GetCurrentDate()
    Dim S$

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://www.fechadehoy.com/venezuela", False
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
        .body.innerHTML = S
        MsgBox .getElementById("fecha").innerText
    End With
End Sub
```

libraries needed for the execution of my macro

```
Microsoft XML, v6.0
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: You do not need to add references if you use late binding.

Comment: It is correct, thanks for your response, the problem is that to add those links you must have activated the option shown in the image.

Comment: There is no problem if you use late binding.

Comment: Side note, please don't do `Dim S$`, think of future maintainers and spell it out: `Dim S As String`. Also consider using an actual meaningful identifier name, e.g. `contents`, or `response`, whatever.

Answer (score 4):

> *in order to access them I must have activated a certain option within the project, is there any way to avoid that?*

The option isn't *within the project*, it's at the host application level (Excel): whether programmatic access to the VBIDE API is trusted or not is an important part of macro security settings, and no, there isn't any way around it.

Any programmatic way to circumvent this security setting would make a huge gaping security hole every macro-virus in the world would jump into.

---

But you don't need to do this. Your code is creating instances of classes located in these libraries using `CreateObject`, not the `New` operator: the references are not needed.

```
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP") ' returns an Object/XMLHTTP reference
    .Open ...  'late-bound member call (no intellisense, no compile-time validation)
    '...
End With
```

`CreateObject` uses the specified ProgID string to find the registration in the Windows Registry, locate the type library, create an instance of the type, and return a reference to that object - everything is resolved at run-time (hence "late" bound), and as long as the ProgID exists in the registry and there's no typo in the late-bound code (`Option Explicit` can't save you from those), everything "just works".

If you used the `New` keyword instead...

```
With New MSXML2.XMLHTTP ' returns an XMLHTTP reference
    .Open ... 'early-bound member call (with intelilsense and compile-time validation)
    '...
End With
```

This couldn't be compiled without a project reference to the `MSXML2` library.